# keras make a custom loss function

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm tying to apply a custom loss function which fits my model.
The labels are binary array of shape (5,), and the position of 1 in the array matters. for example `[1,0,0,0,0]` is `y_true`. `y_pred` as `[0,0,1,0,0]` will have a higher loss than `y_pred` as `[0,0,0,0,1]` have.

The naïve function is below:

```
from keras import backend as K
def tf_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    y_pred = K.clip(y_pred, _Epsilon, 1.0-_Epsilon)
    true = 0
    pred = 0
    tf_session = K.get_session()
    y_true = y_true.eval(tf_session())
    y_pred = y_pred.eval(tf_session())
    shape = y_true.shape

    for row in range(shape[0]):
        for elem in range(shape[1]):
            true += y_true[elem] * elem
            pred += y_true[elem] * elem
    return ((true - pred) ** 2)/shape[0]
```

I know this function is completely wrong, but the idea is there. How can I write a function which I can directly fit into the `model.compile()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for `class_weight`, a parameter that you pass into `fit`:

```
weights = {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5}
model.fit(X, Y, ..., class_weight=weights)
```

---

If you still want that loss function:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss(true,pred):

    weights = K.variable([[1,2,3,4,5]])
    return K.mean(K.square((true-pred)*weights))

model.compile(... , loss =custom_loss)
```

Comment: Both ways work. They exactly fit what I want. Thank you!

Comment: @JerrySmith, Welcome to Stackoverlow :) - I'm glad it helped. When answer are satisfactory, please mark them as answered :)